# htaccess enforcing redirection rule only on staging site, not live site

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https, silverstripe

I have a Silverstripe website at `https://wwww.website.com` 
This website has a uat/staging version of the website at `https://uat.website.com`
These two website have the exact same code base.

This domain has a wildcard SSL certificate that covers it on all URLs except `https://www.uat.website.com`
I have come to learn this is because wildcard certs cannot work on multiple levels.

With this page being unprotected, I have created a redirection rule in my .htaccess file that I'm hoping will do the following:

- Pickup on URLs like `www.uat.website.com` or `https://www.uat.website.com` (including www prefix)
- Redirect them to `https://uat.website.com` (non www prefix)
- Have no effect on the live website `https://www.website.com`
- Have no effect on my local environment

The redirection rule I have used is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.uat.website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://uat.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

As far as I can tell this works, but am hesitant to push the changes up if it will cause issues. Unfortunately, all other redirect rules are handled in the back-end of the platform so I cannot confirm if this will interfere. The only rules enforced by the platform are on the live website and they redirect to the https www version of the domain: `https://www.website.com`

To summarise I need a redirect rule that only effects my staging server, redirecting to the non-www https version of the domain:  `https://uat.website.com`, while not affecting the live website in any way: `https://www.website.com`

Comment: The second condition (RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.uat.website\.com [NC]) is enough to exclude other than www.uat.website.com domains from https forcing. The regular expression actually matches any domain with www.uat.website.com prefix (so for example www.uat.website.com.test.xyz.com) but not www.website.com. If you put $ at the end of the expression it would only match that domain.